# Spreadsheets import html and regex extract errors

Tags: html, regex, spreadsheet

So I'm trying to make a school cancellation calculator... I'm using spreadsheet to gather data from a website source.

The problem is when I extract the needed data with

> =IMPORTHTML("https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/City-ST/ZIP/school-day-weather/18374_pc", "list", 14)

It listed results for the days of the week in column A.

It lists what I want along with a bunch of unnecessary data like temp, cloudiness, precip, etc, which I only want the bus stop conditions which will be "very good/good/fair/poor/very poor at the bus stop".

I tried using

> =REGEXEXTRACT(A2,”.*(bus).*”)

just to try and isolate the word bus to test the functionality and that returns "Formula Parse Error"...

Thanks for the help (:

Comment: Do you enter `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,".*(bus).*")`? It is a valid RE2 pattern. Check the double quotes.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I enter. Can you elaborate on the quotes? I tried fiddling with this:

> =Regextract(importhtml("https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/City-ST/ZIP/school-day-weather/18374_pc", "list", 14), ".*(Bus).*)

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about ``I only want the bus stop conditions which will be "very good/good/fair/poor/very poor at the bus stop".``. Can I ask you about the detail of output result you want?